# I deleted Minecraft pocket edition and it says I need to buy it again

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently deleted Minecraft PE on my apple device. I want to download it again but for some reason it says need to buy it again. I can play it on my phone and not on my iPad. I’m using the same email on both. I’d rather have it on my iPad not on my phone.

Answer (score 4):

In the App Store, click the top-right icon of a person’s silhouette. Click Purchased > My purchases (you may not have to press my purchases if you are not in a Apple family, I don’t know) and then type in “Minecraft”. It should come up with a little cloud icon with an arrow. Click the cloud to download.

Note: if Minecraft was originally bought by someone else in your Apple family, instead of going to Purchased > My Purchases, go to Purchased > (whoever purchased it).

Comment: If you really did buy it, attempting to buy again (clicking the buy in the confirm dialog) with the Apple ID you bought it on won't charge you but instead greet you with a "You already own this" message and download again. This usually happens when you switch app stores countries.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:** First, make sure both of your Apple devices are logged into the same Apple ID, Then, go to "My Purchases" and find Minecraft, then click Install.

**Side-Note:** If you are using Family Library make sure that "Purchase Sharing" is enabled, otherwise only free apps will show up.